# How to create a table as a select from another database in Oracle without a dblink?

Tags: database, oracle

I have two Oracle databases, one on server A, another on server B. I want to create a table in A as a select from B, without creating a dblink. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do it without a database link? Why not export it from one database and import it to another.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_export_utility.htm